# Access locally mysql on docker from remote through SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to access my mysql database from workbench through SSH tunnel, mysql is in a container (working with docker-compose).

Here is my mysql container config in docker-compose :

```
mysql:

image: mysql:5.7
container_name: mysql
expose:
  - 3306
ports:
  - '3306:3306'
volumes:
  - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=#####"
  - "MYSQL_DATABASE=#####"
  - "MYSQL_USER=#####"
  - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=#####"
restart: always
```

But I'm getting a "Failed to Connect to MySQL" error, just like if my ports were not well reforwarding from SSH to MySQL container (and so, not hitting the good door).

Please note I did not allowed remote access from mysql, as I want to only keep SSH/localhost access possible.

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: The `ssh -L` option should forward to the published `ports:` on the container; can you show the actual commands you're running and the actual error you're getting?

Comment: As I'm trying to process my connection through workbench, I have no control on the command, but if I log into the ssh, then try something like :

`mysql -u <mysql_user> -p -h localhost -p 3306`

I get :  `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) `

Comment: The `mysql` client misinterprets `localhost` to specifically mean that socket file; you might see if `-h 127.0.0.1` (using `localhost`'s well-known IPv4 address instead) makes a difference.

Comment: You're right, 127.0.0.1 changed mysql response : `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`. Maybe a binding problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are already exposing port 3306, so you should be able to access it from your system with below command -

```
mysql -u <mysql_user> -p -h localhost -p 3306
```

If not accessible, try if you are able to access it inside the docker session by logging in to mysql container in interactive mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "access inside the docker session" ? What I'm trying to do is basically to login onto the server through ssh, then contacting localhost by hitting 3306.

But I still get an error (see my above comment)

Comment: You cannot access remotely your server mysql db unless you allow incoming traffic for mysql port which is 3306. That's first thing! Secondly if you are ssh'ing in your server and then trying to connect to mysql server which is in your docker image, may be check if your docker container is running. Also make sure whether you are giving the correct credentials.
Will be helpful if you provide output of 'docker ps'.

Comment: You hit a precious thing : is this remote if I'm trying to contact the container from my localhost ? I'm not that familiar with docker, and even if I understand the huge lines, it's still unacurate.

Here is my docker ps line : `mysql:5.7        "docker-entrypoint.s…"    3306/tcp, 33060/tcp `

Comment: I am having hard time reading this. Please post a screenshot on your 'docker ps' output in your question. I am more interested to see the status of container listed in output.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry! It seems to be perfectly fine, as mysql works fine and php application (ran on another container) is connecting to it.

https://prnt.sc/uizuiz